# R: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection -- getting data from an online source

Tags: r

a program that I run frequently all of a sudden throws an error without me having changed anything.

Using the TTR package, I use the getYahooData function to pull stock data. The following command previously worked:

```
getYahooData(symbol = "AAPL", start = 20161002,end = 20170420, freq = "daily", type = "price")
```

I even use the example in the ?getYahooData help documentation:

```
getYahooData("IBM", 19990404, 20050607)
```

In both cases the following error is returned:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
```

My internet is connected and working fine, and I went to the website that getYahooData is accessing and dropped the above parameters into the web address and it successfully generates a csv file with the expected data. Any ideas what the issue might be? Thanks.

Comment: Both work fine for me - might have been a temporary problem at yahoo.

Comment: Very strange. It still doesn't work for me. What version of R and/or R Studio are you using? I wonder if I need to update my version.

Comment: I've got the latest versions of R, RStudio and the TTR package, running on Windows10.  I'd be surprised if an old version was the problem, but you never know. Can you access yahoo quotes through your browser?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your feedback. It was indeed a versioning issue. I updated my version of R to be current and reinstalled the quantmod and TTR packages and it works again. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent.  It was probably TTR.  I seem to remember reading something recently about another package that had an update because yahoo had changed its API, so it might have been the same issue.